# Alt + F4 not working in windows when my background app is running

Tags: c++, windows

I have a C++ offscreen application which runs in the background, i.e., it does not appear in windows taskbar or in the Applications list in task manager. When I press <kbd>Alt + F4</kbd> keys the windows shutdown menu dialog appears for the first time and when I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> key it goes off (as expected). But after this if I press <kbd>Alt + F4</kbd> the windows shutdown menu dialog won't appear. I have to click on the desktop and then press <kbd>Alt + F4</kbd> for the windows shutdown menu dialog to appear again.Any idea why is this behaviour and how to prevent this? When my app is not running and I do this, the windows shutdown menu dialog appears everytime I press <kbd>Alt + F4</kbd> without having to click on the desktop again.

Comment: Is your app running as a service?

Comment: It is running as a process with no UI.

Comment: Is it a console application? Those still opens a window (for the "console") that will receive focus just like any other window.

Comment: It is not a console application. It is a windows app and the UI is off-screen. So not visible to the user.

Comment: Huh, did you make the app invisible by moving the window out of the way? If so, why not make the window invisible by not enabling the "visible" bit? If Windows doesn't know the window isn't supposed to be visible (because you don't tell Windows so), it may give it focus even though the user doesn't see it.

Comment: @hvd But 'Alt + F4' is not killing my app. I can't change the visiblity of the app due to some requirements.

Comment: There are various reasons why Alt-F4 might not close your app, simply ignoring WM_CLOSE messages can do that, so can ignoring all keyboard events before the default handler sees them. I don't know what sort of special things you're doing, so I don't know which of those special things causes this. "Some requirements" is rather vague, can you be more specific?

Comment: You could get your app to watch for window messages indicating that it has received the focus, and to give the focus back to the desktop whenever that happens.  It would be better, however, to sort out whatever issues are making you keep the app visible.  You shouldn't need to do that.